# Problem updating database source on visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I created a database on access and added the data source to my visual studio vb project. However, I have recently added some new fields and tables on my database, how do I update it on my visual basic project without having to delete it and add it as a new data source which caused problems to my programs integrity ?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-run the wizard and update the `DataSet` schema from the Data Sources window.  I'm not in a position to test right now but, if memory serves, you can right-click the specific Data Source and select the appropriate item from the menu. If not, it would be a button on the toolbar in that window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to change the data source, as the data source just refers to the database which has not changed. Ideally, the changes within the database should have reflected in the appropriate DataSet or DataCoulmn in your code. Can you post the code here, so that we can understand exactly what is going wrong?